# How do I detect and re-insert missing data?

Tags: r, data.table, missing-data

I have a missing row in a data table which describes a function from `time`, `sid`, and `s.c` to `count`:

```
> dates.dt[1001:1011]
        sid   s.c  count                time
 1: missing CLICK 104192 2013-05-25 10:00:00
 2: missing SHARE   7694 2013-05-25 10:00:00
 3: present CLICK  99573 2013-05-25 10:00:00
 4: present SHARE  89302 2013-05-25 10:00:00
 5: missing CLICK     28 2013-05-25 11:00:00
 6: present CLICK     25 2013-05-25 11:00:00
 7: present SHARE     15 2013-05-25 11:00:00
 8: missing CLICK 104544 2013-05-25 12:00:00
 9: missing SHARE   7253 2013-05-25 12:00:00
10: present CLICK 105891 2013-05-25 12:00:00
11: present SHARE  88709 2013-05-25 12:00:00
```

the missing row is (I expect a row for each of the two values of the 1st and 2nd columns and each time slice):

```
    missing SHARE      0 2013-05-25 11:00:00
```

How do I detect and restore such missing rows?

The way I discovered this was

```
library(data.table)
total <- dates.dt[, list(sum(count)) , keyby="time"]
setnames(total,"V1","total")
ts <- dates.dt[s.c=="SHARE" & sid=="missing", list(sum(count)) , keyby="time"]
cat("SHARE/missing:",nrow(ts),"rows\n")
stopifnot(identical(total$time,ts$time)) # --> ERROR!
total$shares.missing <- ts$V1
```

Now, I guess I can find the first place where `ts$time` and `total$time`
differ and insert a 0 row there, but this seems like a rather tedious
process.

Thanks!

Comment: *"the missing row is, obviously"* - haha, wat? I think you need to elaborate a little on what different types of omissions you expect to have

Comment: Something like: `rbind` on `cbind(expand.grid(unique(dt$sid),unique(dt$s.c),unique(dt$time)),0)` and then `setkey(dt,...)` to put the inserts in the right places.

Comment: @Frank: thanks for `expand.grid`! how do I find which rows are present in its return value but absent from my original data table?

Comment: Ah, good question. I'm not sure. You could make a sort of key column `mykey:=paste(sid,s.c,time,sep="")` in both the original data set and the `expand.grid` and then compare the `setdiff` of that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Frank's suggestion you can do:

```
setkey(dt, time, sid, s.c)
dt[J(expand.grid(unique(time),unique(sid),unique(s.c)))][order(time, sid, s.c)]
#                   time     sid   s.c  count
# 1: 2013-05-25 10:00:00 missing CLICK 104192
# 2: 2013-05-25 10:00:00 missing SHARE   7694
# 3: 2013-05-25 10:00:00 present CLICK  99573
# 4: 2013-05-25 10:00:00 present SHARE  89302
# 5: 2013-05-25 11:00:00 missing CLICK     28
# 6: 2013-05-25 11:00:00 missing SHARE     NA
# 7: 2013-05-25 11:00:00 present CLICK     25
# 8: 2013-05-25 11:00:00 present SHARE     15
# 9: 2013-05-25 12:00:00 missing CLICK 104544
#10: 2013-05-25 12:00:00 missing SHARE   7253
#11: 2013-05-25 12:00:00 present CLICK 105891
#12: 2013-05-25 12:00:00 present SHARE  88709
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way of doing it. There must be some shorter way of writing the argument to `J()`, though...? Also, why `order` ad the end; isn't the Join still sorted?

Comment: not sure about a shorter way, and yeah, it becomes sorted by `s.c` (first, then `sid`, then `time`) after the join, not really sure why

Comment: ah, duh, it's sorted in the same order as the `expand.grid`, as a join should be