# how can I mutate in dplyr without losing order?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Using `data.table` I can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = 1:2, b = c(1,2,NA,NA))
#   a  b
#1: 1  1
#2: 2  2
#3: 1 NA
#4: 2 NA

dt[, b := b[1], by = a]
#   a b
#1: 1 1
#2: 2 2
#3: 1 1
#4: 2 2
```

Attempting the same operation in `dplyr` however the data gets scrambled/sorted by `a`:

```
library(dplyr)
dt = data.table(a = 1:2, b = c(1,2,NA,NA))
dt %.% group_by(a) %.% mutate(b = b[1])
#  a b
#1 1 1
#2 1 1
#3 2 2
#4 2 2
```

(as an aside the above also sorts the original `dt`, which is somewhat confusing for me given `dplyr`'s philosophy of not modifying in place - I'm guessing that's a bug with how `dplyr` interfaces with `data.table`)

What's the `dplyr` way of achieving the above?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `group_by` calls `setkey` internally. Basically, it doesn't have `ad hoc by`. But I may be wrong here.

Comment: Just as a note, this does not happen when using a regular R data frame.

Comment: It's a bug. Can you please file on github?

Comment: @hadley do you mean just the sorting of the original dt or both?

Comment: @eddi I'm pretty sure it's the same problem, so both.

Answer (score 1):

In the current development version of dplyr (which will eventually
become dplyr 0.2) the behaviour differs between data frames and data
tables:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = c(1,2,NA,NA))
dt <- data.table(df)

df %.% group_by(a) %.% mutate(b = b[1])

## Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
## Groups: a
## 
##   a b
## 1 1 1
## 2 2 2
## 3 1 1
## 4 2 2

dt %.% group_by(a) %.% mutate(b = b[1])

## Source: local data table [4 x 2]
## Groups: a
## 
##   a b
## 1 1 1
## 2 1 1
## 3 2 2
## 4 2 2
```

This happens because `group_by()` applied to a `data.table`
automatically does `setkey()` on the assumption that the index will make
future operations faster.

If there's a strong feeling that this is a bad default, I'm happy to change it.

Comment: thanks, I think it's pretty obvious that you want the same behavior between `data.frame` and `data.table`, and that the `data.frame` behavior is the correct one

Comment: @eddi counter argument: dplyr should take advantage of data.table's performance by default, where possible.

Comment: @hadley, the ideal version would be to allow for both `adhoc-by` and `setkey` during `group_by`. In case that design isn't possible, I'd go with `adhoc-by` personally, as with the recent internal optimisations in 1.9.0+, `adhoc-by` is incredibly fast. Plus, it has no overhead due to the `setkey` operation which'll have to reorder the entire data (think biggggg data). Also, you add a `copy` on top of it, which'll make both memory and time requirements higher. Considering all this, if you've to go with only one of the two, I'd go with `adhoc-by`.

Comment: I doubt you get speed gains by doing this - I'm fairly certain `dt[, b := b[1], by = a]` is faster than `setkey(dt, a); dt[, b := b[1], by = a]` always. But even if you did get performance gains, you should never compromise correctness for performance.

Comment: Maybe having both somehow would be nicer. For example, [Here's a more complex case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878905/data-table-outer-join-by-group) where both `adhoc-by` and `keys` are used.

Comment: @Arun do you know what the `dplyr` analogue of that complex case is?

Comment: @eddi, not to my knowledge.

Comment: Unfortunately the design of `group_by()` makes it very difficult to add additional arguments that are passed on to individual methods. But I'll definitely change the default and think about how to make it an option.

Comment: @eddi I don't think dplyr can handle that well until we add non-materialised cartesian joins

Comment: @hadley Yes if `group_by()` just uses ad-hoc by (i.e. just `by=` and no need for `setkey`) that'll be better.