# filtering data.frame based on row_number()

Tags: r, dplyr

**UPDATE: dplyr has been updated since this question was asked and now performs as the OP wanted**

I´m trying to get the second to the seventh line in a `data.frame` using `dplyr`.

I´m doing this:

```
require(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = runif(10))
df <- df %>% filter(row_number() <= 7, row_number() >= 2)
```

But this throws an error.

```
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I know i could easily make:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% filter(rn <= 7, rn >= 2)
```

But I would like to understand why my first try is not working.

Comment: `df %>% filter(row_number() %in% 2:7)`

Comment: I could do that too, but why `df <- df %>% filter(row_number() <= 7, row_number() >= 2)` is wrong?

Comment: I don't know the real reason behind that.  A double `filter` appears to work.

Comment: `row_number()` does not get you the row number...

Comment: It's a bug. Please file an issue on https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues

Comment: Is this question still valid, it doesn't seem to give an error anymore, it could be confusing if it isn't flagged as outdated

Comment: It's working for a long time now. Should I delete it?

Comment: I think it is useful to have around as long as it is clear, that it is now out of date, this way, people (like me) looking for help can see that this is not a problem. I edited the post for clarity.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Actually dplyr's `slice` function is made for this kind of subsetting:

```
df %>% slice(2:7)
```

(I'm a little late to the party but thought I'd add this for future readers)

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful as the error reoccurred for me. I later found out that this is a inconsistency with how row_number() treats data tables, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23861047/unique-rows-in-dplyr-row-number-from-tbl-dt-inconsistent-to-tbl-df

Answer (score 29):

The `row_number()` function does not simply return the row number of each element and so can't be used like you want:

• ‘row_number’: equivalent to ‘rank(ties.method = "first")’

You're not actually saying what you want the `row_number` of. In your case:

```
df %>% filter(row_number(id) <= 7, row_number(id) >= 2)
```

works because `id` is sorted and so `row_number(id)` is `1:10`. I don't know what `row_number()` evaluates to in this context, but when called a second time `dplyr` has run out of things to feed it and you get the equivalent of:

```
> row_number()
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

That's your error right there.

Anyway, that's **not** the way to select rows.

You simply need to subscript `df[2:7,]`, or if you insist on pipes everywhere:

```
> df %>% "["(.,2:7,)
  id        var
2  2 0.52352994
3  3 0.02994982
4  4 0.90074801
5  5 0.68935493
6  6 0.57012344
7  7 0.01489950
```

Comment: The purpose of `row_number()` is definitely to return the row number (hence the name!) and this behaviour is a bug.  (Also you don't need `.` in your piping example)

Comment: Note to anyone thinking `row_number` shows the `row_number` code. It doesn't. You want the `row_number_prototype` C++ function.

Comment: Would you care to explain how the `"["(.,2:7,)` syntax works? It's really interesting solution.

Comment: Its just the way almost everything in R can be written as a function. Try `"+"(1,3)`.

Comment: @Konrad as alternative you can write, slightly more readable than the "[" syntax:
    df %>% .[2:7, ]

Comment: @Spacedman is correct, row_number does *not* return exactly the row number as vector, see e.g. the output of `datasets::airquality %>% row_number`. If you want to use it as an index vector containing the row number, you must convert it to a numeric vector like `datasets::airquality %>% row_number %>% as.numeric`

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to do row-number based filtering in a pipeline.

```
    df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = runif(10))

    df %>% .[2:7,]

    > id     var
      2  2 0.28817
      3  3 0.56672
      4  4 0.96610
      5  5 0.74772
      6  6 0.75091
      7  7 0.05165
```

Comment: It's slower than `slice`, but it does't drop `NA` (e.g. `df %>% .[c(NA,2,4,7),]`) which could be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `subset`:

```r
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var = runif(10))
subset(df, row.names(df) %in% 2:7)
#>   id        var
#> 2  2 0.75924106
#> 3  3 0.17096427
#> 4  4 0.10886090
#> 5  5 0.98703882
#> 6  6 0.04190195
#> 7  7 0.73268672
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>